# How to replace letters in a string using translate method?

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def lazy_encrypt(string, dic):
    string = string.translate(dic)
    return string
```

If I run this code:

```
print(lazy_encrypt("Here is a pretty simple message to encrypt", {"e": "o", "o": "a"}))
print(lazy_encrypt("When it's encrypted, it will look different", {"e": "o", "o": "a"}))
```

My output should be:

```
Horo is a protty simplo mossago ta oncrypt
Whon it's oncryptod, it will laak difforont
```

My original code used replace method:

```
def lazy_encrypt(string, dic):
    for i in string:
        if i in dic:
            string = string.replace(i, dic[i])

    return string
```

However I get the output:

```
Hara is a pratty simpla massaga ta ancrypt
Whan it's ancryptad, it will laak diffarant
```

Comment: `string = string.translate(str.maketrans(dic))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.translate()` uses ASCII values for it's dictonaries.

```
print(lazy_encrypt("Here is a pretty simple message to encrypt", {"e": "o", "o": "a"}))
print(lazy_encrypt("When it's encrypted, it will look different", {"e": "o", "o": "a"}))
```

should be:

```
print(lazy_encrypt("Here is a pretty simple message to encrypt", {101: 111, 111: 97}))
print(lazy_encrypt("When it's encrypted, it will look different", {101: 111, 111: 97}))
```

Which should get your desired result.
Anyway, shouldn't it be easier to use [string.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

Comment: I added my original code in the question using replace method. It didn't work because it replaced the letters twice.